# Pandas read CSV file with column headers separated by ;

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple CSV file with 5 columns and 100 rows. The first 3 rows (with header)
looks like this.

```
Week;Name;Number;Trial;Final
1;Test;10;1.355454;4.5555
2;Test;20;10.3524642;10.0900
3;Test;30;7.4424525;50.00005
```

As you can see, the column names are separated by `;`, and thus when I try the following:

```
In [20]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')                            

In [21]: df.head(3)                                                              
Out[21]: 
         Week;Name;Number;Trial;Final
0   1;Test;10;1.355454;4.5555
1   2;Test;20;10.3524642;10.0900
2   3;Test;30;7.4424525;50.00005

In [22]: df['Week']
KeyError: 'Week'
```

This is because my 5 columns are being read as one single column.

```
In [25]: df.columns                                                             
Out[25]: Index(['Week;Name;Number;Trial;Final'], dtype='object')
```

How can I read all my columns and proceed with analysing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
```